# How to pass mapkit coordinate from view controller(mapView) to detail controller (mapView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I have a json file with different Longitude and Latitude, I can show them in my mapView in view controller when I click on annotation of one of them, I can go to detail view, In detail view I have a small map view, I want to show the coordinate of annotation that has been clicked,

would you please help me in this implementation, Thanks in advance!

appreciated any code in answer part!

Here is implementation of map view in my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
 _mapView.delegate = self;
    [self fetchData];
}



 -(void)fetchData
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASED_URL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[GETReply bytes] length:[GETReply 
length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];


CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                         
NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply
                                                 options:0
                                                   error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    // handle the error 
}

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{

    location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    // create the annotation
    MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;


    newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];
    newAnnotation.coordinate = location;     
    [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
}
[self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
}
```

Here is how I passed data to my detail view controller:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
 {


 MyAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;

UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.navigationController.storyboard;

//the detail controller
DetailViewController *detail = [storyboard   
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

detail.companyData = annotation.company;
I don't know how to pass coordinate to mapView in detail view
```

my question is how to pass coordinate and show it on map view on detailview

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

}

Here is the code for my detailedView:

```
@synthesize companyData = _companyData;
@synthesize detailMapView = _detailMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_company.text = _companyData;
```

I don't know how to add it on __detailMapView

```
}
```

Comment: You need to store coordinate data in `CLLocationCoordinate2D`  and manage in another view

Comment: @iPatel thank you for your comment, appritiated if you can write you example in answer part

Comment: In DetailViewController, you've declared the companyData property.  Did you try adding a property for the coordinate?  What happened when you tried that?  Also, you could just declare an `annotation` property in DetailViewController and just pass the whole annotation object so DetailViewController will have access to all the annotation information so you don't have to pass the fields one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your `detailView`'s .h-file:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;`

In the callout-method, add the following:

`detail.coordinate = annotation.coordinate;`

And use the coordinate-property in the viewDidLoad of your detailView:

```
    MyAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.coordinate = _coordinate;     
   [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation]
   [self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,appreciated if you can also show the usage part of coordinate in viewDidLoad of the detailView

Comment: You'd already shown us code where you added an annotation to a MKMapView so I figured you knew how that worked already. But I've updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I did it like this :    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = _coordinate;
    [_detailMapView addAnnotation:point];